# Jquery Validate bug on IE : [Object object]

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, razor, jquery-validate

I've a problem with my JQuery Validate on IE and FF (it works fine on Chrome).
That redirect me on a blank page with only "[Object object]" displayed.
Edit : In fact, the page load correctly the error message but reload to this blank page less than one second after.

Here's my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myForm').validate(
            {
                rules: {
                    Quantity: { required: true, number: true, min: 1 }
                },
                messages: {
                    Quantity: { required: 'QuantityRequired', number: 'QuantityDigit', min: 'QuantityRequired' }
                },
                errorLabelContainer: '#errorList',
                wrapper: 'p'
            });
        });
```

And cshtml :

```
<div id="errorList"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Management", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm" })) {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <label>NumberVoucherConcern *</label>
 <span>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity)</span>
 <a href="javascript:$('#myForm').submit();">Send</a>
}
```

I thought about a library conflict, or something else, but when I comment this JS part it works fine...

Any idea ? Thank you for your time !

Comment: Please only show the _rendered_ HTML as seen by the browser, not your server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using an anchor, `<a>` tag, in place of a proper submit button, there's no need to use inline JavaScript...

```
<a href="javascript:$('#myForm').submit();">Send</a>
```

You can use jQuery instead...

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="send">Send</a>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myForm').validate({  // initialize validate plugin
        // ..... // your rules & options
    });

    $('#send').on('click', function(e) {  // capture click of anchor
        e.preventDefault();     // block the default anchor behavior
        $('#myForm').submit();  // submit the form
    });

});
```